# Chrome extension permission XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am coding  a chrome extension for first time. Read out their documentation well, specially permission section.

I want to load a JSON response from my localhost with a specific port ex. 3000.

I updated my mainfest.json and persssion section is like

```
  "permissions": [
    "http://localhost:3000/*"
  ],
```

But getting `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/project/data.json Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Seems I am missing something.

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks good. Did you reload the extension after adding the permission? Is the AJAX code running in the extension's process or content script?

Answer (score 0):

You could try any of the following solutions:

1. Add the following line to the end of your manifest file:

   ```
   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://localhost:3000; object-src 'self'"
   ```
2. Instead of `localhost`,try using the address instead i.e `127.0.0.1`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your request is sent to the same host with other port then this is already a cross domain request (please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules). Cross domain ajax requsts are not allowed.
There are two solutions:

1. To use JSONP request.
2. To add to the response header an option: **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *** But not all browsers support this feature.

Please see:

- [jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: While this information is relevant to ordinary Web pages, is not relevant to Chrome extension development, since Chrome extensions have the ability to [relax the same-origin policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html). This questions asks about an attempt to use this ability in a Chrome extension.